# phpmyadmin with java. Is there a way to get the strings from phpmyadmin and compare it with the input from the keyboard?

Tags: java, database, phpmyadmin, database-connection

What I want to do is compare each word in the phpmyadmin database (columns and rows) with the user input from the keyboard. I know I can do this with a CSV file with equalsIgnoreCase. But I can't seem to find any tutorials that is similar to what I am trying to do. If anybody know of how to do this with code example or video please send it.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 tables in phpmyadmin:
1st table store the values you want.
2nd table store the user inserted values.
use group by query to compare both tables.